# FB.login using Facebook JavaScript SDK in mobile web browser opens new tab instead of native Facebook App

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a website which uses FB SDK on JavaScript, the website calls FB.login and request permissions for an app which I have in Facebook(Facebook Apps), when a user click on submit button in web browser, a popup appears and asks for permissions to the user who is logged in and have session (continue as "Person Name"), in case there is no session it will ask for account details then ask for permissions and it works fine.
The the is responsive and works for mobile too, so in mobile when a user clicks on submit button it open a new tab instead of native Facebook app and usually users are not logged in with their mobile browsers, I use the code below:

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: 'appId',
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true,
                version: 'v3.1'
            });
            FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
        };

        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        
        function fbLogin() {
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    // Get and display the user profile data                    
                    getFbUserData();
                } else {
                    console.log = 'User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.';                 
                }
            }, { scope: 'email' });
        }
        
        function getFbUserData() {
            FB.api('/me', { locale: 'en_US', fields:'id,first_name,last_name,email,link,gender,locale,picture.width(640)' },
                function (response) {
                    //make somthing
                });
        }
```

The question is, how can I ask for permissions by opening native Facebook App instead of a new tab in browser in mobile devices? is this possible?

Comment: No, that is not possible. There is no connection between the browser and the native app that would enable this.

Comment: this is weird, because to trigger the native app to open is possible (fb:// or facewebmodal), but opening the app the ask for permission for developer app is not possible?